# firefox Kiosk with button to close it

Tags: firefox, kiosk

is there a way to show a close button in firefox while in kiosk mode? `firefox --kiosk`

All I need is to show just an X to close firefox, no tabs, other controls etc.

If it's a limitation, alternatively all window controls (minimize, maximize, close) can be shown instead, but preferably only a button to close firefox.

> System: Ubuntu Mini 18.04 Upgraded to 20.04 with Xorg and Openbox installed + firefox

Comment: Why bother with a button? Put a note on the PC to use *Alt-F4* to close Firefox.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik 3 words: touchscreen, no keyboard. + it's counterintuitive